# Get previous two URLs from next router object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-router

this is my code:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const App = () => {
    const router = useRouter()

    return null
}
```

`router` object has `NextRouter` type. However, this type don't have `components` property, whereas runtime value has.

So, `components` property is an object where keys are previous URLS.

**My question is:**

How to get exact previous URL. AFAIK, object keys are unordered data structure. Is it possible to do in next/router ?

P.S. I did not find any information in [nextjs/router docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) about `components` property.

I also left a question in nextjs [community chanel](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39502)

Comment: Please let me know if my question is not clear so I will be able to improve it

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39502) you can find an answer